# How to add custom validation in expresssion engine validation

Tags: ee3

This is my current code.

```
$rules = array(
    'label'        => 'required',
    'short_name'   => 'required',
);

$result = ee('Validation')->make($rules)->validate($_POST);
```

Now I want it like this:

```
$rules = array(
   'label'        => 'required',
   'short_name'   => 'required|trim|check_name["test_name"]',
);
```

but I am getting error in trim rule.

> Unknown validation rule `trim`.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because **trim** function is not defined in current validation library. You need to add your own function in EE3 before you run validation.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/development/services/validation.html#custom-rules):

You first need to create an object of Validation class.

```
$validator = ee('Validation')->make();
```

Then you need to define your custom rule:

```
$validator->defineRule('trim', function($key, $value, $parameters)
{
  return ** Depends on result return TRUE or Error Message **;
});
```

Then you need to use that rule with setRules.

```
$validator->setRules(array(
   'age' => 'required|trim'
));
```

Final step is to validate your post data:

```
$result = $validator->validate($data);
```

$result will either contains TRUE or object of errors.